# How to Connect LiveLink Using LAPI SingleSignOn

Tags: asp.net, single-sign-on

Can anyone guide me as to how can i connect to LiveLink through LAPI using Single Sign On.I need to get the connectionstring.

Regards,
Vix

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the config parameter in LL_SessionAllocEx. There you can configure EnableNTLM. However, SSO only works with Java.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Java EasyLAPI framework on the OpenText Knowledge Center.  It contains some sample code for transparently authenticating using SSO.